# Terraform ELB access_log S3 access Permissions Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb, terraform

I am having issues with terraform when I am trying to create an s3 bucket for my elb access_log I get the following error below:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.elb-author-dev.aws_elb.elb: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_elb.elb: Failure configuring ELB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: my-elb-access-log. Please check S3bucket permission
status code: 409, request id: 13c63697-c016-11e7-8978-67fad50955bd
```

But, If I go to AWS console and manually give permissions to my s3 Public access to everyone. Re-run terraform apply it works fine, please help me resolve this issue.

#### My main.tf file

```
module "s3-access-logs" {
  source = "../../../../modules/aws/s3"

  s3_bucket_name       = "my-elb-access-data"
  s3_bucket_acl        = "private"
  s3_bucket_versioning = true
  s3_bucket_region = "us-east-2"
}
 # elastic load balancers (elb)
module "elb-author-dev" {
  source           = "../../../../modules/aws/elb"
  elb_sgs          = "${module.secgrp-elb-nonprod-
author.security_group_id}"
  subnets          = ["subnet-a7ec0cea"]
  application_tier    = "auth"
  access_logs_enabled = true
  access_logs_bucket  = "my-elb-access-log"  
  access_logs_prefix  = "dev-auth-elb-access-log" 
 access_logs_interval = "5"
 instances           = ["${module.ec2-author-dev.ec2_instance[0]}"]
}
```

#### my s3/main.tf

```
  resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_data_bucket" {
    bucket = "${var.s3_bucket_name}"
    acl    = "${var.s3_bucket_acl}" #"public"

    region = "${var.s3_bucket_region}"

   policy = <<EOF
  {
   "Id": "Policy1509573454872",
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
      "Sid": "Stmt1509573447773",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-elb-access-log/dev-auth-elb/AWSLogs/my_account_id/*",
      "Principal": {
      "AWS": [
          "033677994240"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  versioning {
    enabled = "${var.s3_bucket_versioning}" #true
  }
  tags {
    Name        = "${var.s3_bucket_name}"
    Terraform   = "${var.terraform_tag}"
 }
}
```

#### My elb.main.tf

```
  access_logs {
    enabled       = "${var.access_logs_enabled}"  #false
    bucket        = "${var.access_logs_bucket}"
    bucket_prefix = "${var.environment_name}-${var.application_tier}-${var.access_logs_prefix}"
    interval      = "${var.access_logs_interval}"  #60
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terraform ELB S3 Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366038/terraform-elb-s3-permissions-issue)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## AWS Bucket Permissions

You need to grant access to the ELB principal. Each region has a different principal.

> **Region,  ELB Account Principal ID**
>
> us-east-1, 127311923021
>
> us-east-2, 033677994240
>
> us-west-1, 027434742980
>
> us-west-2, 797873946194
>
> ca-central-1, 985666609251
>
> eu-west-1, 156460612806
>
> eu-central-1, 054676820928
>
> eu-west-2, 652711504416
>
> ap-northeast-1, 582318560864
>
> ap-northeast-2, 600734575887
>
> ap-southeast-1, 114774131450
>
> ap-southeast-2, 783225319266
>
> ap-south-1, 718504428378
>
> sa-east-1, 507241528517
>
> us-gov-west-1*, 048591011584
>
> cn-north-1*, 638102146993

* *These regions require a separate account.*

*source:* [AWS access logging bucket permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions)

**Update**
Looks like the info is no longer available at the link I posted. I haven't been able to find its new location. If someone locates it please posta comment and I'll update this answer accordingly.

## Terraform

In terraform your resource config should look like the example below. You will need your aws account-id and the principal id from the table above:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_data_bucket" {
    bucket = "${var.s3_bucket_name}"
    acl    = "${var.s3_bucket_acl}"
    region = "${var.s3_bucket_region}"

    policy =<<EOF
{
"Id": "Policy1509573454872",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Sid": "Stmt1509573447773",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-elb-access-data/dev-auth-elb/AWSLogs/your-account-id/*",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["principal_id_from_table_above"]
    }
    }
]
}
EOF
}
```

You may need to split the policy out separately rather than keeping it inline as above. In which case you'd need to add a bucket policy resource like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "elb_access_logs" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_data_bucket.id}"
  policy =<<EOF
{
"Id": "Policy1509573454872",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Sid": "Stmt1509573447773",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-elb-access-data/dev-auth-elb/AWSLogs/your-account-id/*",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["principal_id_from_table_above"]
    }
    }
]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: I ran terraform and received the same error. I update my s3/main.tf above and still fails. Any ideas what am I missing

Comment: your bucket name doesn't match its 'my-elb-access-data' in main.tf and 'my-elb-access-log' in the resource name in s3/main.tf. I'll update my answer since it also doesn't match...

Comment: If you want to get the principal IDs from a lookup table, you can create a variable with a map:

`
variable "alb_logging_principals" {
  type = "map"
  default = {"us-east-1": 127311923021,"us-east-2": 033677994240,...}}`

And look it up in the S3 bucket section: `"AWS": ["${var.alb_logging_principals[var.aws_region]}"]`

Comment: For your "Region, ELB Account Principal ID" list. How did you get this list of IDs?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me from the AWS documentation `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html#attach-bucket-policy`

```html
   {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

elb-account-id was replaced with 127311923021 as for me it was N.Virginia region.