# Terraform: Setting up logging from AWS LoadBalancer to S3 bucket

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an aws_lb that I want to log to an S3 bucket.

What I have unsuccessfully tried to do:

```
data "aws_elb_service_account" "main" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    sid       = ""
    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn}"]
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lb-logs-role" {
  name = "lb-logs-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "lb-logs-role"
    Environment  = terraform.workspace
    Management   = "Managed by Terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3-logs-access" {
  name = "s3-logs-access"
  role = aws_iam_role.lb-logs-role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

This is the error I am seeing:

```
Error: Failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: my-bucket. Please check S3bucket permission
        status code: 400, request id: 5b629210-9738-11e9-bcc6-6f3b4f22bf28

  on modules/tableau-linux/lb.tf line 1, in resource "aws_lb" "main":
   1: resource "aws_lb" "main" {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add errors that you are facing by editing question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terraform ELB S3 Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366038/terraform-elb-s3-permissions-issue)

Comment: I have added the error. Don't know how helpful it is.

Comment: I have tried the code from the possible duplicate, to no avail. Don't know if that matters, but that question uses an aws_elb, not aws_lb.

Comment: @JosephTura please check I test with Terraform version `Terraform v0.12.1`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the API will request the ACL of the bucket to see if it has permission, and populate the initial folder structure, therefore the even though the `aws_elb_service_account` has permissions to `putObject` in the bucket the api call will fail. This policy is what the AWS web console creates when it creates the S3 bucket for you, and it solved it for me.

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
data "aws_elb_service_account" "main" {}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "lb-bucket-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lb-log-storage-s3.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "${data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn}"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-log-storage-s3.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-log-storage-s3.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-log-storage-s3.arn}"
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is with your policy but you can try my code using aws_lb, Here is the complete configuration to launch to LB in default VPC and create bucket named `test-bucket-1-unique-name`, policy and LB named `test-http-lb`. Along with SG and Route53 entry that is commented.

```
# Creating Load Balancer
resource "aws_lb" "httplb" {
  name                       = "test-http-lb"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = ["${aws_security_group.lbsg.id}"]
  subnets                       = ["subnet-99fdf8e0", "subnet-902b0ddb"]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  access_logs {
    bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}"
    prefix  = "http-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "test-http"
  }
}


# Creating Security Groups for Load Balancer
resource "aws_security_group" "lbsg" {
  name        = "test-loadbalancer-sg"
  description = "test-Allow LB traffic"
  tags = {
    Name = "test-SG-Balancer"
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    description = "HTTP"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}










#uncomment this if you want to add route53 record
# resource "aws_route53_record" "web" {
#   zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
#   name    = "${var.env_prefix_name}.ironman.co
#   type    = "A"

#   alias {
#     name                   = "${aws_lb.httplb.dns_name}"
#     zone_id                = "${aws_lb.httplb.zone_id}"
#     evaluate_target_health = true
#   }
# }




data "aws_elb_service_account" "main" {}

# Creating policy on S3, for lb to write
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "lb-bucket-policy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Id": "testPolicy1561031527701",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "testStmt1561031516716",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-1-for-lb-logs/http-lb/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
           "${data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-1-for-lb-logs"
  acl    = "private"
  region = "us-west-2"

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
  force_destroy = true


}
```

Then go to your S3 bucket and verify `TestFile`.
[image]
Here are the logs from terraform

[image]

Comment: @Joseph did you try this.

Answer (score 0):

This one stumped me also, but I got it working with this

```
        {
          Effect : "Allow",
          Principal : {
            "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"
          },
          Action : [
            "s3:PutObject"
          ],
          Resource : "${aws_s3_bucket.logging_bucket.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*",
        }
```

Where does `127311923021` come from, you ask? Believe me, I did too!  [This AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#attach-bucket-policy) says it is the *ID of the AWS account for Elastic Load Balancing for your Region* (us-east-1 in this case).  It has a large table of these magic numbers!