# S3 IAM error while "put" ing logs from ALB to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

**s3.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role_replication" {
  name = "tf-iam-role-replication-12345"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy_replication" {
  name = "tf-iam-role-policy-replication-12345"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
         "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete",
        "s3:ReplicateTags"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "replication" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_role_replication.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_replication.arn
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_slave" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-slave-"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_slave_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.bucket

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.s3_kms_key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "s3_bucket_slave_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_master" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-master-"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_master_alb_put_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Id": "Policy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}/access-logs-bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "${data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.bucket
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.s3_kms_key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "s3_bucket_master_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_replication" {
  # Must have bucket versioning enabled first
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.s3_bucket_master_versioning]

  role   = aws_iam_role.iam_role_replication.arn
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id

  rule {
    id = "foobar"
    delete_marker_replication {
      status = "Disabled"
    }
    filter {
      prefix = "foo"
    }

    status = "Enabled"

    destination {
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket_master_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket_slave_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_bucket_master_public_access" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  restrict_public_buckets = true
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_bucket_slave_public_access" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  restrict_public_buckets = true
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id

  target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  target_prefix = "log/"
}
```

**alb.tf**

```
####################################################
# Target Group Creation
####################################################

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "lb_tg" {
  name        = "alb-target-group"
  port        = 80
  target_type = "instance"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

####################################################
# Target Group Attachment with Instance
####################################################

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "tg_attachment" {
  count            = length(aws_instance.instance.*.id) == 3 ? 3 : 0
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.lb_tg.arn
  target_id        = element(aws_instance.instance.*.id, count.index)
}

####################################################
# Application Load balancer
####################################################

resource "aws_lb" "lb" {
  name                       = "alb"
  internal                   = true
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.sg.id, ]
  subnets                    = aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id
  drop_invalid_header_fields = true
  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.bucket
    prefix  = "access-logs-bucket"
    enabled = true
  }
  enable_deletion_protection = true
}

####################################################
# Listner
####################################################

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.lb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}


####################################################
# Listener Rule
####################################################

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.lb_tg.arn

  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/var/www/html/index.html"]
    }
  }
}
```

**data.tf**

```
# Get user 
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

# Get Account 
data "aws_elb_service_account" "main" {}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting errors like the below:

```
╷
│ Error: failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: s3-bucket-master-20220713230235453200000002. Please check S3bucket permission
│       status code: 400, request id: 17cb8a1b-d914-4fe5-b6cd-5db02f335cc4
│
│   with aws_lb.lb,
│   on alb.tf line 27, in resource "aws_lb" "lb":
│   27: resource "aws_lb" "lb" {
│
╵
```

I followed the article from [Terraform ELB S3 Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366038/terraform-elb-s3-permissions-issue)

I am struggling to understand what exactly is the issue!?

P.S
Edit 1: Amended the S3 Resource Name as per recommendation but I am still getting the error of access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have just copy/pasted the example from the documentation [1]:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_master" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-master-"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_master_alb_put_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Id": "Policy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-elb-tf-test-bucket/AWSLogs/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "${data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

If you look at the ARN it is for a bucket that does not exist:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::my-elb-tf-test-bucket/AWSLogs/*"
```

You want the ARN of the master bucket if I am reading this right. So you would use the following ARN and the prefix defined in the `prefix` argument of the `access_logs` block in the `aws_lb` resource:

```
"${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}/access-logs-bucket/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.id}/*"
```

EDIT: The prefix has to be there along with the `AWSLogs` and the AWS account ID as per [2].

EDIT 2: As per the documentation [2], one of the requirements is to use SSE-S3 encryption:

> Requirements
>
> - The bucket must be located in the same Region as the load balancer.
> - Amazon S3-Managed Encryption Keys (SSE-S3) is required. No other encryption options are supported.

Currently, in you code you seem to be using the AWS KMS master key ID for bucket encryption:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.bucket
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.s3_kms_key.arn # KMS master key
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}
```

If you switch that to:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.bucket
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}
```

After you make this change, the code should work as expected.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/elb_service_account#example-usage

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html

Comment: Ok, the IAM policy error has gone but still access denied error persists.

Comment: Are the bucket and LB in the same account?

Comment: Yes, all are in the same account.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sadly, still the same error.

Comment: What does the bucket policy show in the AWS console? Has the interpolation done its job? Do you see the AWS account ID for the ALB? Can you add that to the comment and/or question?

Comment: @learner Please take a look at EDIT 2, as I think that might be the last issue with the code you have.

Comment: I also figured it out the same at the same time:) I created manually and could push the logs then I compared them with the TF snippet! Yep, KMS was causing the grief.